# Excel - For each unique ID, every time a particular column turns one, it needs to be cumulatively added

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, countif

I have a big data set. What I want to happen is for each customer number occurrence, when the transaction type column has an entry CC or SO, it needs to be calculated as a donation. So for each occurrence in the future the spreadsheet should cumulatively add. How can I to do this?

For instance, 5680 is a customer number, each time a customer is called a new row is created in sql database. I copy them to excel to analyse. 5680 might have made a donation in April, July and October. So his Number of Donation column(Last Highlighted column) must change accordingly. His entry in April will have 1, July will have 2 and october will have 3.

So if the transaction type(Second highlighted column, has "CC"(credit card) or "SO"(send-out). Then that means a donation. So every time a raw is iterated, it should check it history. If the person has donated before then the number of donations should increment.

I have highlighted the columns that need to be considered in silver.
[image: My Spreadsheet]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the expected results are? I'm unclear what you're trying to get from this. Where do you want it to "cumulatively add"? A count of all donations from that customer into Column P?

Comment: For instance, 5680 is a customer number, each time a customer is called a new row is created in sql database. I copy them to excel to analyse. 5680 might have made a donation in April, July and October. So his Number of Donation column(Last Highlighted column) must change accordingly. His entry in April will have 1, July will have 2 and october will have 3.

Comment: So if the transaction type(Second highlighted column, has "CC"(credit card) or "SO"(send-out). Then that means a donation. So every time a raw is iterated, it should check it history. If the person has donated before then the number of donations should increment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to test how many times a given customer has made a donation (CC or SO) previously, so this is effectively a running count of how many donations this customer has made.

Try this formula in P2 and copy down:

```
=IF(OR(J2="CC",J2="SO"),SUM(COUNTIFS(A$1:A2,A2,J$1:J2,{"CC","SO"})),0)
```

Explanation: tests if the line is a CC or SO. If so, it then does a COUNTIFS which conditionally counts all occurrences where A$1:A2 equal the current customer and J$1:J2 match CC or SO. The "$" is to ensure the range always starts at the top row, but ends on the current row. If the row isn't a CC or SO, the first test fails and the result is 0 (the last bit of the formula)--change it to whatever value you want for a non-donation record.

The results:

[image: sample worksheet]

Customer 5680 had 4 entries, but only 3 were valid donations (CC or SO), so it gets counted up to 3.

Comment: Hey Rob I have another problem in the same file. Could you help me? I have posted it as a question in here, If you could help me, it would be great. Thanks

http://superuser.com/questions/1007013/changing-and-updating-a-future-value-based-on-past-occurence-in-excel

Comment: hey rob, there is a problem in the answer. The number remains 0, in the user's future entries. But I wnat them to be one, as they have a history of 1.

Answer (score -1):

If the value is A1 then `=IF(OR(A1="CC",A1="SO"),1,0)`.

You can then use a sum formula to get a total

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, using a sum will sum all the entries, but i want to filter them for each customer and it needs to be cumilative for unique customer id.